# Why does my browser try to open ads from fwdsnp.com?

Tags: dns, browsing, adware

When I browse to some retail websites, my browser briefly directs to fwdsnp.com. From there it tries to open a popup and then forwards to the site that I actually want. I first noticed this with dell.com. I initially thought it was adware I had accidentally installed. However, it happens for all computers in my home and "fresh installs."

Why?

Comment: If you have a router or switch, check its DNS settings.
Otherwise, check your computer's DNS settings. And also check your computers for viruses (yes, they can be inside all your home computers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spoke to my ISP. They said it is their DNS service that does this. They said if I don't like it I can use a different DNS service.

Comment: They really should have said change their ISP :) They shouldn't do this. For DNS, the two big ones are Google DNS (good cause they are fast, bad because that's yet another bit of info you send Google) and there's OpenDNS.

Comment: A blog post about this particular ISP and their DNS trick: http://erichelgeson.github.io/blog/2013/12/31/i-fought-my-isps-bad-behavior-and-won/